# What is the efficient way to iterate a list in scala?

Tags: scala, performance

I am new to scala, I am iterating list of tuple (String, Map(String, Double)). My tuple list has just 6 elements and  ._2 has just one key value pair. While I iterate first element alone takes 300ms to process. I am just building another Map using |+| semigroup operator. Subsequent element takes 1 or less milliseconds. Wondering what would be the efficient way. I tried foreach and iterator.foreach both giving similar latency for the first element.

Comment: How are you measuring performance? Scala usually uses just-in-time compilation so performance gets better as the code runs.

Comment: For most modern programming language implementations, the general rule is: if your measurement says that your code is slow, there is a 90% chance that you are measuring it wrong, a 9% chance that you are interpreting the result of the measurement wrong, a .9% chance that your code is horribly inefficient, and only the rest is caused by the language implementation itself.

Comment: Whenever I *think* I know how to benchmark my code, I re-read the whole thread at https://groups.google.com/g/mechanical-sympathy/c/m4opvy4xq3U/m/7lY8x8SvHgwJ just to remind me how *incredibly, mindbogglingly complex* proper benchmarking is and how *incredibly subtle* the problems are. After that, I pull out my statistics textbook from university to remind myself just how complicated the proper interpretation of the benchmark's results are, even assuming that the benchmark itself were correct (which more than likely it is not).

Comment: @Tim yes during first time only it takes more time. Subsequent runs its 10 times better. Say we are having 20 machine, first call fails due to latency exceeding 300 milliseconds. So 20 calls failing. Whenever a machine restarts/replaced first call failing. But is there a way to speed up first call as well?

Comment: The more interesting question is always: is the data structure appropriate for my use case? Do you need mutation? Do you always iterate from start to end, only partly, or do you need random access? Do you want to sacrifice immutability for performance? Depending on these answers you can select List, Vector, Array, etc.

Comment: Can you provide a code for better understanding?

Comment: Much better to make the client robust to a timeout, because the server might get busy at any time, not just startup. The client should re-issue the request on timeout, with some back-off policy if there are repeated timeouts.